# How to stop mLastKnownLocation from returning null on app's first load on emulator

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I'm using the emulator to test my app.
And if I wipe all the data off the emulator and start the app then using the following methods from the android developer docs:

```
 getLocationPermission();

 updateLocationUI();

 getDeviceLocation();
```

throws an error because on the first use of the app mLastKnownLocation is null.

I've read quite a few posts about this and the issue seems to be that opening the app on a device that has never used it's location service seems to be the problem because no last location has ever been recorded.

So that's all cool but i'm struggling to implement a simple solution. There are a few posts about mGoogleApiClient

```
GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
    .enableAutoManage(this /* FragmentActivity */,
                      this /* OnConnectionFailedListener */)
    .addApi(Drive.API)
    .addScope(Drive.SCOPE_FILE)
    .build();
```

But not sure how that solves the problem.

I was wondering if, after getLocationPermission is true, there is a simple way to force locationservices to turn on and get the devices location?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For make it simple, try with this library https://github.com/mrmans0n/smart-location-lib. You can get it for just once.

You just put this code if you want get location once time

```
SmartLocation.with(context).location()
    .oneFix()
    .start(new OnLocationUpdatedListener() { ... });
```

Comment: Thanks @Deni but i'm not really after a library. Just wouldn't mind a simple solution to what I think is a simple problem.

Comment: @Mike
you just put this code if you wan't to get location for once 

SmartLocation.with(context).location()
    .oneFix()
    .start(new OnLocationUpdatedListener() { ... });